# Custom DLL to avoid the IE web browser control for "unsafe controls" in a tightly controlled and regulated environment

Tags: vb.net

Scenario:

My company has a legacy (read that as 32 bit) windows form application that will be around for quite some time in the future.  This application uses an embedded web browser control that is supplied pages that are contained within the database that it maintains.  It was built like this so we could extend/modify as needed.  I say this so that I can validate that security is not a concern.  Only the application and developers with the correct tools have access to the pages or database. The application is only available inside the office.

There are some processes that I need to accomplish using ActiveX objects that are embedded within the pages/application.  One of the biggest and most annoying thing that happens is the ActiveX security warning when I got to create instances of things like “scripting.filesystemobject”.  Example:

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

My solution is to create a DLL that is installed locally on each machine that needs access to the extended functions, have the all the functions (whole DLL ??) marked as safe so that the web browser control does not present the security warning.  I have been searching using google and came across very few examples, and all of which are in C# which is not my strongest language.

I’ve had to convert from C to Vb.Net visual basic to get what I have now.  When I go to register my DLL, I get the following error message:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>regasm 
Z:\VBNet2017\APIInternal\APIInternal\bin\Debug\APIinternal.dll /tlb
Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version 4.8.4084.0
for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.8.4084.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Types registered successfully
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Type 'APIInternal.API.Accupay' has an invalid default COM 
interface: 'APIInternal.API.Accupay'
```

UPDATE: Thank you Hans; the error is gone.  I've also made some changes in the source code; I changed the ProgID to something that closely resembles where and what this is for.  I'm still having issues in creating the object in VB Script.

This is the output from the current version of the code. This is the code, stripped down for clarity:

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.IO

Namespace API
  Public Interface IAccupay
    <DispId(1)>
    Function GetFiles(ByVal Folder As String) As List(Of String)
End Interface

<Guid("8B4B5CEF-8B3A-49A1-9053-E909F82D9E73"),
    ProgId("AddIn.Accupay"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
        ComDefaultInterface(GetType(IAccupay)), ComVisible(True)>
Public Class Accupay
    Implements IAccupay

    Private Function GetFiles(Folder As String) As List(Of String) Implements IAccupay.GetFiles
        Return Directory.GetFiles(Folder).ToList
    End Function
End Class
```

I have tried just about every combination of ProgID, Name space, Interface name and class name to get this error to go away without any luck.  I do know there are other elements that need to be addressed or added, such as error trapping and, if I’m not mistaken, how to actually implement the ObjectSafetyOption which I still don’t know how to do.

I have been using the Guide at the bottom of this article:
[Is it possible to mark an ActiveX object as safe so that IE settings need not be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136232/is-it-possible-to-mark-an-activex-object-as-safe-so-that-ie-settings-need-not-be), the second answer, but I haven’t had any success.

Please, can someone point me in the right direction, maybe show me what’s wrong with the code that I have and how to physically implement the ObjectSafteyOption that is needed for the web control.  Links, additional reading, code examples or comments on how to get this fixed and working would really be appreciated.

Thank you for reading and any help you send my way, Fred
PS: If you need more information, or have a better solution, please don’t hesitate to reply or comment.

UPDATE:
With the code that I have now, I am able to access the DLL in VB.Net visual basic:

```
Imports System
Imports APIInternal.API

Module Program
  Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim API As New Accupay
    Dim FileList = API.GetFiles("C:\Windows\")
    For Each Item As String In FileList
        Console.WriteLine(Item)
    Next
  End Sub
End Module
```

However, I still can't seem to get the correct calling for a VB Script/html page:

```
Set Test = CreateObject("Test.Accupay")
```

Which returns the VB Script error "ActiveX Component can't create object: Test.Accupay  or any other iteration of the parts of the name that I tried.  I think part of this is that I don't understand how the creation of the project leads to the creation of the object in a com base environment like VB Script.

Fred

Comment: Accupay is not an interface so can't be the default.  Edit to ComDefaultInterface(GetType(IAccupay))

Comment: Hans - That fixed the error!  Thank you!  All I need to figure out now is how to access the DLL via VB Scripting, then eventually as a Safe DLL in the web control.  Again, thank you.  I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is two fold:  You must target the correct platform (X86) AND use the 32 bit version of regasm.  Once I realized this was the issue, I was able to create the DLL and use it's functions in the Web Browser control without the active X warning.  One example is I can now open the default browser (in this case, NOT IE/EDGE) from a link within the WB Control and another is to get the contents of a folder for further processing within the WB page.